# Excel copy function with rotation

Tags: excel

I have a spreadsheet with two portions, the first's rows are usernames and columns are data types (availability, ID, email etc), the second's rows are the data types and columns are the usernames. The second's values must be calculated based on what is in corresponding cells in the first. The second isn't simply copied from the first, each cell contains calculation based on multiple columns of the first portion.

I have been asked to keep these as they are currently, as in don't just create new new columns in the first portion or rotate the second.

**So my question is:** is there a way that I can copy a function across columns in a way that the variable changing by column is the row number not the column number?

I know the thing I'm trying to do makes no sense. Makes no sense to me neither, but this is what I've been asked to do.

Comment: There is no pre-built way to do it as far as I know. In these cases I always use a combination of `INDIRECT` and `CONCATENATE`. Then you just need to have an index across the columns which indicates the row it is supposed to be pulling data from. This index will feed your `INDIRECT` formula. Then you can copy and paste all the cells as values, delete the initial data and you're done.

Comment: Ended up using a whole bunch of `INDIRECT(ADDRESS())` and `MATCH` functions, thanks for the help so I didn't waste more time looking for a "magic function"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ended up using a whole bunch of `INDIRECT(ADDRESS(MATCH, MATCH))` functions to get the values then get the desired values from them into the second portion.

A second table or extra column would've been so much cleaner but hey, to each their own.